# Separar renglones de CSV por "/" python

Tags: python

Necesito hacer unos cambios en mi csv.
busco separar los rows que tenga en country por la "/" y duplicarlos.
Basicamente explico un poco porque necesito hacer esto:
Cuando tengo una "/" en el row de `Country`significa que son ambos paises y por cuestiones tecnicas necesito que haya solo un país por renglon.

ejemplo:

```
*,CA - Canada/UK - United Kingdom,0.45
output:
*,CA - Canada,0.45
*,UK - United Kingdom,0.45
```

Data:

```
Space,Country,Price
*,AR - Argentina,0.3
*,CA - Canada/UK - United Kingdom,0.45
*,CL - Chile/PE - Peru,0.25
*,CO - Colombia/EC - Ecuador,0.15
*,CR - Costa Rica/ES - Spain,0.2
*,DE - Germany,0.5
*,MX - Mexico,0.4
*,US - United States,0.8
```

Lo que busco:

```
Space,Country,Price
*,AR - Argentina,0.3
*,CA - Canada,0.45
*,UK - United Kingdom,0.45
*,CL - Chile,0.25
*,PE - Peru,0.25
*,CO - Colombia,0.15
*,EC - Ecuador,0.15
*,CR - Costa Rica,0.2
*,ES - Spain,0.2
*,DE - Germany,0.5
*,MX - Mexico,0.4
*,US - United States,0.8
```

Code:

```
import csv
with open("pre.csv", 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    your_list = list(reader)
    print your_list

divididos = []
for item2 in your_list:
    if "/" in item2[1]:
        a = item2[1].split('/')
        print item2[0] + ',' + a[0] + ',' + item2[2] + ',' + item2[3]
        print item2[0] + ',' + a[1] + ',' + item2[2] + ',' + item2[3]
    else:
        print item2
```

Comment: Saludos Martin,bienvenidoa StackOverflow en Español, por curiosidad ¿Qué has intentado más allá de cargar el archivo CSV?

Comment: Gracias! Si, pero no encontre en otros lados lo que busco y he pensado bastante y soy bastante nuevo en python @fredyfx

Comment: ¡No se diga más! Click: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/index.htm y ve por más aprendizaje :D Edita tu pregunta y agrega todo aquello que has pensado porque aquí valoramos mucho el esfuerzo de quienes se las buscan y eso nos motiva a dar una mano con más ganas :D buena suerte, por cierto, entra a https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso obtengas tu primera medalla :D

Comment: te ayudo con el algoritmo: lee cada línea, revisa si existe el caracter "/", de ser cierto, divide esa línea por el caracter de la coma "," al hacer esto la cadena *,CL - Chile/PE - Peru,0.25 se dividirá en [0] = "*", [1]="CL - Chile/PE - Peru" y [2]="0.25". a ese [1], extraes la segunda parte "PE - Peru", lo mandas a otra variable, eliminas la actual posición dejando CL - Chile. creas un nuevo string: le colocas "*," concatenado con la variable que contiene "PE - Peru", le pones concatenas la "," [2] que era 0.25 y a toda esta cadena la insertas al final o donde desees en el CVS

Comment: con esto espero haberte ayudado, cuando lo hagas funcionar, agrega tu respuesta para que seas el héroe de más personas :D

Comment: Si pretendes hacerlo directamente en pandas, y no mediante bucles recorriendo el csv por líneas, [aqui tienes algunas soluciones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116814/pandas-how-do-i-split-text-in-a-column-into-multiple-rows) que puedes adaptar a tu caso, pero cuidado, son alta magia negra.

Comment: Edite mi pregunta, agregando hasta donde avance peor no me sale lo proximo @fredyfx

Answer (score 1):

Aca esta la respuesta!

```
import csv
import itertools

with open("pre.csv", 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    your_list = list(reader)

divididos = []
primeros = []
for item2 in your_list:
    if "/" in item2[1]:
        a = item2[1].split('/')
        p1 = item2[0] + ',' + a[0] + ',' + item2[2] + ',' + item2[3]
        p2 = item2[0] + ',' + a[1] + ',' + item2[2] + ',' + item2[3]
        p1 = p1.split(',')
        p2 = p2.split(',')
        divididos.append(p1)
        divididos.append(p2)
    else:
        primeros.append(item2)

separados_ok = divididos + primeros

with open("output.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(separados_ok)
```

Comment: Lo has logrado, enhorabuena!

Comment: Esoooo!!! felicitaciones hermano :D Elevaste el cosmos y le diste con todo el power 2.0!!! Sigue así :D Recuerda marcar tu respuesta como aceptada en 23 horas 39 minutos

Comment: Recuerda seleccionar la respuesta final.

Answer (score 1):

Ahora que ya ha aparecido una respuesta (y del propio autor de la pregunta!) con una solución que podríamos llamar "clásica", mediante un bucle `for` que itera por las líneas, voy a poner yo otra solucion mucho más "esotérica" que hace uso de las funciones de pandas, adaptada de las respuestas a [esta pregunta similar en Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116814/pandas-how-do-i-split-text-in-a-column-into-multiple-rows).

Esta solución es mucho más ilegible, y por tanto menos recomendable, salvo por una importante razón. Al hacer uso de las primitivas pandas en lugar de código python, es mucho más veloz, si bien esto sólo se apreciará si el csv a procesar es muy grande.

Con el siguiente dataframe como entrada:

```
>>> df = pandas.read_csv("pre.csv")
>>> df
  Space                          Country  Price
0     *                   AR - Argentina   0.30
1     *  CA - Canada/UK - United Kingdom   0.45
2     *             CL - Chile/PE - Peru   0.25
3     *       CO - Colombia/EC - Ecuador   0.15
4     *       CR - Costa Rica/ES - Spain   0.20
5     *                     DE - Germany   0.50
6     *                      MX - Mexico   0.40
7     *               US - United States   0.80
```

El siguiente conjuro:

```
aux=df.Country.str.split("/").apply(pd.Series, 1).stack()
aux.index = aux.index.droplevel(-1)
aux.name = "Country"
del df["Country"]
result = df.join(aux)[["Space", "Country", "Price"]]
```

produce el resultado deseado:

```
>>> result
  Space              Country  Price
0     *       AR - Argentina   0.30
1     *          CA - Canada   0.45
1     *  UK - United Kingdom   0.45
2     *           CL - Chile   0.25
2     *            PE - Peru   0.25
3     *        CO - Colombia   0.15
3     *         EC - Ecuador   0.15
4     *      CR - Costa Rica   0.20
4     *           ES - Spain   0.20
5     *         DE - Germany   0.50
6     *          MX - Mexico   0.40
7     *   US - United States   0.80
```

Por lo que basta ahora hacer `result.to_csv("output.csv")`

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Siguiendo la misma lógica que en tu autorespuesta (iterar sobre las filas y usar `str.split`) podemos hacer lo mismo  pero evitando crear listas intermedias usando iteradores y modificando un poco la lógica. Esto es especialmente importante si tu csv es relativamente grande para preservar memoria y reducir el tiempo de procesamiento del csv. Además, el código se simplifica notablemente eliminando muchos pasos intermedios que son ineficientes como la concatenación de cadenas :

```
import csv

with open("pre.csv", 'rb') as in_f, open("output.csv", "wb") as out_f:
    reader = csv.reader(in_f)
    writer = csv.writer(out_f)
    writer.writerow(next(reader)) # Escribimos la cabecera
    writer.writerows(((space, div, price) for space, country, price in reader
                                              for div in country.split("/")))
```

En principio esto debe ser más eficiente tanto en uso de memoria como en tiempo de ejecución que cualquier alternativa en Pandas o similares al evitar el parseo de los datos y la construcción integra del DF en memoria y posibles copias completas o parciales del mismo durante el procesamiento. Otra cosa es que tu objetivo no sea simplemente crear otro csv, sino trabajar con los datos en Pandas, en cuyo caso habría que valorar que opción es mejor.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!